# How to simulate an Altera megafunction using Modelsim SE

Tags: vhdl, fpga, modelsim

___Hi, everyone. I have instantiated a `PLL` using the Megawizard in Quartus II. Then I wanted to simulate it using `ModelSim SE` because Quartus II 10.1 doesn't have a built-in simulator. I copied *builtInPLL.vhd* (output of the Megawizard) and *PLL_tb.vhd* (testbench) to the directory of the ModelSim project. But when I compiled *builtInPLL.vhd*, it gave out the following error messages:

> Error: builtInPLL.vhd(39): Library altera_mf not found.
>   Error: builtInPLL.vhd(40): (vcom-1136) Unknown identifier "altera_mf".

relevant lines in *builtInPLL.vhd*:

> LIBRARY altera_mf;
>   USE altera_mf.all;

I googled these messages but found nothing really helpful. I copied *altera_mf.vhd* from `..\eda\sim_lib` and compiled it with *builtInPLL.vhd*. Modelsim still gave me the messages above. And many files with suffix `.dat` and `.dbs` were created in the work directory. What are they?

Where is the library `altera_mf` located? And how can I simulate a megafunction using ModelSim SE.
Any help will be appreciated.Thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Standard ModelSim SE does not come with Altera library support, so you have to
install the Altera specific libraries like `altera_mf`.  There is an example
Tcl script for this at [ModelSim Tcl Scripting
Examples](http://web.archive.org/web/20130707091650/http://www.altera.com/support/examples/tcl/tcl-modelsim.html) under [Library Setup Script (VHDL)](http://web.archive.org/support/examples/download/vhdl-library-setup.tcl).

As an alternative you can consider using the ModelSim-Altera version, which
comes with pre-installed Altera libraries, like the `altera_mf`.  This ModelSim
version can be found at [ModelSim-Altera
Software](http://dl.altera.com/?edition=subscription&product=modelsim_ae#tabs-2).
There is even a free version called "ModelSim-Altera Starter Edition".

Answer (score 1):

Quartus II also has an interactive tool for this:

> Tools > Launch Simulation Library Compiler > ...